# Unit testing - Practicality: Should it pass or fail all or most of the time?

Tags: unit-testing, agile

Here's a **philosophical** question on unit testing, from a **Practicality** perspective: Should test cases pass or fail all or most of the time?

Couple points:

1. If you're practicing TDD, unit tests are expected to fail initially. Point is you start dev
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development
2. If unit test fails all the time and the software still released to production - it simply means developers not fixing either the test cases, or test case is irrelevant/useless.
3. If unit test fails all the time and the software **NOT** released to production - it means there's still work to be done by developers before production launch.
4. If unit test never fails, this also suggest the test case is **useless**?
   But then, this reminds me of "Titanic" :)

I mentioned **Practicality** - test cases takes time/resources to develop too. There's no point writing too many useless testing. World is not "Test Driven" afterall. It's business/money driven.

Comment: This might be better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Better fit for SoftwareEngineering.SE https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4):

If a unit test fails, it indicates that something's not working: either the System Under Test (SUT) doesn't work, or the unit test doesn't work.

If the unit test doesn't work, it should be fixed or removed.

If the SUT doesn't work, it means that you have a defect in your system. In that case, your highest priority should be to address the defect.

At each check-in, **all tests should pass**.

You'll see tests fail initially when you do TDD, and that's [the reason you can trust them](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/02/why-trust-tests). As part of the TDD *red/green/refactor* cycle, though, at the end of each iteration, you should be left with an all green test run. That's the whole point.

Thus, tests should pass most of the time.

Comment: Thanks Mark - in other words, although under TDD developer first build test which fails, upon check-in (ideally) or latest before tagging a release, all test should pass.

Comment: @user3761555 You write *one* test, see it fail, make it pass, refactor, and repeat. This is called the [Red/Green/Refactor cycle](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html). Follow it, and you should only have at most *one* failing test at any given time.

Comment: I would add that writing well-designed and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) tests and test data is every bit as much as an acquired skill as writing well-designed and DRY application code. Most people don't pay much attention to test architecture and design, instead thinking that the unit testing and mocking frameworks are all the "design" their tests need. The whole thing devolves into an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: Indeed, [TDD isn't a design methodology](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/22/TheTDDApostate).

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from a misunderstanding of the TDD process. Most of the time 100% of your test should pass. They should be passing when you commit your code to version control. They should be passing when you refactor your code. And they absolutely should be passing when you release your code.

Typical TDD is:

1. Create a new test
2. See it (and only it) fail
3. Write code to make it pass
4. See it pass (and all others pass). If not goto step 3
5. Refactor as required

Sometimes an integration or unexpected change will cause other tests to fail. But that should be either resolved immediately or reverted. It's not something that is ignored and evaluated later.